# Как при клике на input открыть календарь?

Tags: javascript

Всем привет есть такой [**плагин**](https://tempusdominus.github.io/bootstrap-4/)  календарья

Надо чтобы он открывалсья при клике на input.(Также как и на иконку)

При этом первая версия тоже работало.То есть везде внутри инпута если кликнуть чтобы открывалсья календарь.

Это надо чтобы user не смог писать ничего   там где надо писать только дату

```
<br/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker2" data-target-input="nearest">
          <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#datetimepicker2" />
          <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#datetimepicker2" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(function() {
  $("#datetimepicker2").datetimepicker({
    locale: "nb"
  });
});
```

Ссылка на [**Codepen**](https://codepen.io/saintjon/pen/ERmXZY)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Изменить `input` таким образом, указать вызов `datetimepicker` в `data-toggle`.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#datetimepicker2" data-toggle="datetimepicker"/>
```

Comment: Простите но это не вариант там должен быть изначально placeholder.А в вашем решении placeholder туда не поставить

Comment: А в чем проблема placeholder?

Comment: прошу извинить все работает ответ принят плюс поставил  спасибо огромное :)